# Beep in Windows Service in C#

Tags: c#, windows-services

I want to play a beep in my windows service in especial situation but I cannot.
I try several methods like : Kernel32, `System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play()` and `Console.Beep()`, `Console.WriteLine(@"\a")`.
But none of them was useful.
So what can I do to solve my problem?

Comment: Are you talking about making the  PC speaker beep like what happens when you reboot the computer?

Comment: Did you try to `Beep()` in regular application?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1286194/21567. Note that the link in the answer is dead, but might still give a hint.

Comment: One of the main points of services is that they can run all the time the machine is running, even if *no one* is logged in. So you may be able to make a beep, but it's possible that nobody hears it. What are the consequences then?